# How to upload images with same extension at one time HTML5

Tags: html

Using HTML5 upload multiple is it possible to have a wildcard upload. Means if user gave *.jpg in browse option is there any possibility to upload all the images that having the .jpg extension.

```
<input id="upload" type="file" multiple />
```

I have researched about it and couldn't found any thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the `multiple` attribute will let users select multiple files to upload to you, but they still need to select them themselves.

Comment: Yes i know but i am looking for possibilities if any

Answer (score 0):

The downvoting might be because you're asking a question that has no reason for an answer!

Now look why?

```
<input id="upload" type="file" multiple />
```

This attribute here is meant to be selecting multiple files, doesn't include which type of files. So you can just filter out either images, or you can select audio, how? Here is code

```
<input id="upload" type="file" multiple accept="image/*" />
```

This will let the File Selector, only let the user select the files that are images.

Now to go further deep in the coding and selecting out images that have only the perfect type of format that you want. You'll require a server-side coding. Then at the serverside you can check for the fileExtension for each file selected, and save each file that has .jpg file extension and leave others without saving them.

However, not going in the bottom and just check each file in JS, you can use jQuery to check their fileExtension, split their names at '.' and check the last value that you get.

This way, you will get the required result. But `multiple` doesn't do that.